# Iterating over a dictionary with value as a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dictionary 'mydict'.

```
{   'a': ['xyz1', 'xyz2'],
    'b': ['xyz3', 'xyz4'],
    'c': ['xyz5'],
    'd': ['xyz6']}
```

I'm trying to print out all the keys and values of this dictionary using the following code:

```
for username, details in mydict.iteritems():
    pprint.pprint(username + " " + details)
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show your actual code

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In Python 3+ you don't need to use `iteritems()` you can use just `items()`. Also, it seems to me like you made a list instead of a dict, so it would be great if you could show your actual code.

Comment: So `mydict` is not a `dict`, but a `list`. That's what the error message tells you.

Comment: Sounds like your dict is not really a dict but a list...try it again with a dict.

Comment: @Ashwin There must be a part of your code where you modify `mydict` into a list, or it has always been a list, either way it's not what you are showing here

Answer (score 1):

This code works on your example

```
>>> import pprint
>>> mydict = {   'a': ['xyz1', 'xyz2'],
    'b': ['xyz3', 'xyz4'],
    'c': ['xyz5'],
    'd': ['xyz6']}

>>> for username, details in mydict.iteritems():
        pprint.pprint((username, details))


('a', ['xyz1', 'xyz2'])
('c', ['xyz5'])
('b', ['xyz3', 'xyz4'])
('d', ['xyz6'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I get the same AttributeError when I attempt the original, this arrises becuase the VALUE in each KEY, VALUE pair is a list.

Using mydict.items() you can create a copy of each (KEY, VALUE) pair, which you can then print:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    print((key, value))
```

Though of course, creating a copy using items() is memory expensive if your dictionary is large. Which, is the big advantage (lower memory cost, more efficient AND ****optimised*** for python*) of being able to use iteritems() to iterate through your dictionary.

Equally well, you could do the following:

```
for key in d:
    print((k, mydic[key]))
```

BUT (in python), this is slower again! Because you have to re-hash the dictionary each time as you look up `mydict[key]`. So, it seems that mydict.items() is the best option here, as it gives you access to the values directly through tuple unpacking.

Raymond Hettinger (the iteritems and generator guru from Python) gave a great talk at US PyCon, which you can watch here: http://pyvideo.org/video/1780/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-pytho